# Resharper 10 autocomplete takes a fraction of a second to display after I finish typing - how do I make it instant?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

Say for example I am assigning a value to a boolean variable. I start typing 'fa' and hit return, and Visual Studio immediately fills out 'false' - I do not need to wait for the intellisense popup window.

In Resharper, the autocomplete suggestions are just as good but the window takes a split second to appear. I can't immediately hit 'return' after I type 'fa'. It just inserts a new line.

It doesn't sound like a huge issue but coming from the built in Intellisense this is really annoying.

Is there a way to make 'return' function like it does with the default intellisense?